# Drawing to paragraph in Dart

Tags: html, performance, dart, paragraph, dart-html

I use GameLoop, which is depedent on Canvas, but works even without it. I have an array of chars which I draw to the paragraph almost every render frame. Lines are divided with `</br>`. Each time I check if there has been any changes in the array and if it needs to be redrawn.

Almost every char has got its class so it looks like this:
`< span class="my_css_class">CHAR< /span>` (without spaces). So each char has it's css style.

The performance is great on the computing side, but rendering to the paragraph costs a lot of CPU usage. Is there a better way of how to render to paragraph with more efficiently?

The array is about 40x80 chars.

The code which renders the chars:

```
if(!Utility.isDuplicate()) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
        sb.write(array[i][j]);
      }
      sb.write("<br />");
    }
    querySelector("#main_paragraph").innerHtml = sb.toString();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do most characters change or just a few?

Comment: Just a few. About 20 I guess.

Comment: It worked kind of great until I've added thos span tags, but they are necessary.

Comment: Can you please add some code that shows how you do the DOM manipulation?

Comment: I've added it to the post.

Comment: I personally don't like the term "drawing" on paragraph here. You just set the HTML Code within the container or whatever #main_game is. Maybe you want to create a predefined matrix with span's and give it IDs and only change the contents of the span's instead of writing it completely.

Comment: I've tried doing that and it resulted in even worse performance. It was unplayable.

Comment: I guess using a canvas here might solve your problem. How does your final game look like (graphically)?

Comment: Well, as you've probably guessed, it's ASCII based. CSS are required, so canvas is probably not an option.

Comment: Maybe you can add multiple elements to the DOM and then show() hide() depending on your needs? That should be much quicker than removing / parsing from/into DOM.

Comment: That would work only if the number of element was not so big. The game array/"resolution" I have is about 40x80 chars.

Comment: How are the chracters being displayed? Just a chracter and the class defines the color?

Comment: The class defines the shadow + color. The final paragraph is a composition of all those chars and spans.

Comment: So how many FPS do you have? Are you using workers?

Comment: The problem is now fixed. Apparently, I had one unclosed tag which caused so many performance issues. Weird.

Comment: Ok. Just for completeness: http://animatr.rhscripts.de/asciigame/asciigame.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this can't be done using paragraphs as the whole HTML processing is too cumbersome and differs from browser to browser. Consider moving to canvas or some WebGL which should provide much better performance.